# Update processing time from unit test for stateless operator

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to test a Flink stateless operator, in which the logic makes decisions based on current (processing time).  One option is for the Operator to extend `KeyedProcessFunction` which will allow manipulating the Processing time from the Unit Test (using `KeyedOneInputStreamOperatorTestHarness<>.setProcessingTime()` ), even though the Operator is a stateless Operator.  Is there a better / cleaner option?

Any pointers or link to sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,
Ahmed.

Answer (score 0):

Have your stateless function implement a protected `getProcessingTime()` method, which normally returns `System.currentTimeMillis()`. During testing, use a class that extends your function's class, and overrides this method with one that returns a value you can set explicitly during testing.

Basically you're implementing support similar to what the test harness does.